# GCP Deployment manager - Call HTTP endpoint when everything is deployed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I have a template that creates a few resources in GCP, and I want it to either call an HTTP endpoint or publish a message to a topic whenever the deployment completes. I've been checking different services all day, and couldn't find anything about it.

In AWS, it is quite easy to deploy an SNS message that is published to an SNS topic, which is subscribed to SQS Queue, and that triggers a lambda function. In Azure ARM templates, we can use az CLI to invoke a web request and call an endpoint directly.

I couldn't find any similar in GCP. Is there any way of either calling an HTTP endpoint, Cloud Function or perhaps publishing a message to a topic whenever a deployment is finished?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I think this answer will help with your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785197/how-to-initially-we-can-invoke-cloud-function-from-deployment-manager/72828190#72828190

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in GCP is to [Create a Logging Sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#creating_sink) using a filter and the [Logging query language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language) to only send the Deployment Manager logs to a PubSub topic.

Here is an example of a sink sending deployment manager logs to a PubSub topic previously created:

```
gcloud logging sinks create $SINK_NAME pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/$YOUR_PROJECT/topics/$TOPIC \
  --log-filter='resource.type="deployment"' --description="my sink"
```

Be careful to [Set the destination permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-auth) or will not see the logs in the PubSub topic.

Once you are getting the logs in the PubSub topic, you can configure [Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) to fire up an HTTP call based on content of the log.